# 400 Bad request when using Get-IntuneConditionalAccessSetting within the Microsoft.Graph.Intune module

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

It appears that the other get commands for Intune are working, such as compliance and configuration policies but when I attempt to use the Get-IntuneConditionalAccessSetting command I always get the following:

```
Get-IntuneConditionalAccessSetting : 400 Bad Request
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "{\r\n  \"_version\": 3,\r\n  \"Message\": \"An error has occurred - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - 
Activity ID: 66a698b9-a2ae-4559-ad06-9a22fd2d69f7 - Url: 
https://fef.amsub0102.manage.microsoft.com/StatelessOnboardingService/deviceManagement/conditionalAccessSettings?api-version=2018-08-13\",\r\n  
\"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",\r\n  \"RetryAfter\": null,\r\n  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",\r\n  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"\r\n}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "66a698b9-a2ae-4559-ad06-9a22fd2d69f7",
      "date": "2020-04-30T08:08:24"
    }
  }
}
At C:\Data_TempFilesOnly\PowerShell\ConditionalAccess.ps1:131 char:26
+             $IntuneObj = Get-IntuneConditionalAccessSetting | ForEach ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (@{Request=; Response=}:PSObject) [Get-DeviceManag...lAccessSettings], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PowerShellGraphSDK_HttpRequestError,Microsoft.Intune.PowerShellGraphSDK.PowerShellCmdlets.Get_DeviceManagement_ConditionalAccessSettings
```

I have tried the command on its own and it produced the same error so I don't think its the actual code and is specific to the command. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/conditionalAccessSettings` is for on-premise Exchange Conditional Access, so returns error 400 if on-prem exchange isn't configured.

If you're looking for AzureAD Conditional Access, use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/conditionalAccess/policies`

Comment: Hi,  I have replied below to your question, but basically it looked like I needed to add permissions within Graph Explorer (not used it before) and now I get the same error as running the command in PowerShell and that is a bad request 400 error

Comment: I don't have enough rep to add comments except on my own answers, so will discuss here.

Just to confirm, you've configured Exchange on-prem Conditional Access as per [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-device-based-conditional-access-on-premises)? This API is for on-prem only, not AzureAD Conditional Access.

Comment: It looks like this command gives me exactly what I need and it works: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//conditionalAccess/policies

Answer (score 0):

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "{\r\n  \"_version\": 3,\r\n  \"Message\": \"Application is not authorized to perform this operation. Application must have one of the following scopes: DeviceManagementServiceConfiguration.Read.All, DeviceManagementServiceConfig.Read.All, DeviceManagementServiceConfiguration.ReadWrite.All, DeviceManagementServiceConfig.ReadWrite.All - Operation ID (for customer support): 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 - Activity ID: afb69295-20c4-424e-b55b-15274fd6ab1a - Url: https://fef.amsub0102.manage.microsoft.com/StatelessOnboardingService/deviceManagement/conditionalAccessSettings?api-version=2018-08-13\",\r\n  \"CustomApiErrorPhrase\": \"\",\r\n  \"RetryAfter\": null,\r\n  \"ErrorSourceService\": \"\",\r\n  \"HttpHeaders\": \"{}\"\r\n}",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "afb69295-20c4-424e-b55b-15274fd6ab1a",
            "date": "2020-04-30T09:29:01"
        }
    }
}

If this is a permissions problem how do I add the permissions to this application?

Comment: I have now added the permissions within Graph Explorer and I get the same error as PowerShell and that is a code 400 bad request error